# Activating cell after button click (remove focus from the button)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a sheet with one button (a shape) which is associated with an Apps Script function.

[image]

When I click the button it inserts a row and activates a cell in that row.

[image]

Then if I try typing, nothing happens. I manually need to click on the new cell to be able to enter new text...

How can I change the code to be able to immediately start typing just after the click of the button (without additional click on the cell)?

```
function above_same_level() {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var row = ws.getActiveRange().getRow();
  ws.insertRowsBefore(row, 1);
  ws.getRange('A' + row).activate();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55088373#55091280) is pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> right after the mouse click on the button.

It's slightly more comfortable than using mouse, but it's still an intermediate step.